# Getting Intellisense to work with imported .tlh files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, com, intellisense

I've recently discovered that Intellisense does not work with `#import`ed type libraries -- even after the first compile, after the `.tlh` is generated.

For example, if this code is compiled, and the `.tlh` file is generated, Intellisense will still not know the methods available for the pointer:

```
#import "libid:00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" raw_interfaces_only auto_rename

Outlook::_ApplicationPtr pOl(__uuidof(Outlook::Application));
```

If you start to type `pOl.` or `pOl->`, Intellisense will say, "No additional information available."

I was wondering if there were any workarounds for this.  I've already tried the following things, to no avail:

- deleting the `.tlh` and `.tli` files and starting over
- deleting the entire build and starting over
- deleting the `.vs` folder and starting over
- explicitly `#include`ing the full path of the `.tlh` file
- explicitly `#include`ing the full path of the `.tlh` file and commenting out the `#import`
- rescanning the `.tlh` file via the context menu
- changing the attributes of the `#import` statement and starting over
- making sure Visual Studio is up-to-date
- uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio

Thank you for any additional ideas.

Comment: IntelliSense is brittle, and more often than not gets confused. Though I have no experience with importing type libraries, what frequently works is opening the respective header file and optionally running *"Rescan"* -> *"Rescan File"* from the editor's context menu. See if you find squiggles under any of the `#include` directives and do the same for those files.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, but it didn't work, so I've added it to my list.

Comment: Report a bug to Microsoft. If intellisense doesn't work properly, they are the only ones who can fix it. The joys of closed source software ...

Comment: You can check the diagnostics detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-cpp-intellisense-configuration?view=vs-2019#validate-project-settings-with-diagnostic-logging